# Foreach array display a item 2 time

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to mail my client all of his purchased product as lest. So my query select product by its order id from ord_product table.

My **ord_product** table structure and entry is:

```
id  | product_id |  order_id | name     |  quantity  |  price
______________________________________________________________
1   |   100      |    1000   | Monopoly |      2     |  5.00

2   |   101      |    1000   | Chases   |      1     | 20.00
```

Now my problem is after my script Its display my 1st product Monopoly 2 times at Client email.

Here is my ord_product query

```
$rt = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ord_product WHERE order_id='$o_id'") or  die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
    $newrow[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['product_id'] = $row['product_id'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['price'] = $row['price'];

    foreach($newrow as $array){

        $subtotal = ($array['price']*$array['quantity']);

        //echo result at mail
        $message .= "<p><b>Name : </b>".$array['name']." <span><b>Qty : </b>".$array['quantity']." pcs </span><span><b>Price : </b>AUD ".$array['price']." </span><span><b>Total : </b>AUD ".$subtotal." </span></p>";

        mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE allproduct SET sold=sold+1 WHERE id= '".$array['product_id']."'");
     }
}
```

At my client email its echo:

```
Name: Monopoly  Qty : 2  Price : 5.00   Total : AUD 10.00
Name: Monopoly  Qty : 2  Price : 5.00   Total : AUD 10.00 // echo again
Name: Chases    Qty : 1  Price : 20.00  Total : AUD 20.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$rt = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ord_product WHERE order_id='$o_id'")    or  die(mysqli_error($dbh));  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
     $subtotal = ($row ['price']*$row ['quantity']);
    $message .= "<p><b>Name : </b>".$row ['name']." <span><b>Qty :   </b>".$row ['quantity']." pcs </span><span><b>Price : </b>AUD ".$row ['price']."   </span><span><b>Total : </b>AUD ".$subtotal." </span></p>";
    mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE allproduct SET sold=sold+1 WHERE id= '".$row ['product_id']."'");
 }
}
```

Comment: Change `$subtotal = ($array['price']*$array['quantity']);` to `$subtotal = ($row['price'] * $row['quantity']);`

Answer (score 0):

Keep foreach loop out of while loop. After completing `while` loop than start `foreach` loop. If you keep into while loop than append into `$message` in every loop. Best practice after completing `while` loop than start `foreach` loop.

```
$rt = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ord_product WHERE order_id='$o_id'") or  die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
    $newrow[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['product_id'] = $row['product_id'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
    $newrow[$row['id']]['price'] = $row['price'];    
}

foreach($newrow as $array){    
  $subtotal = ($array['price']*$array['quantity']);    
  //echo result at mail
  $message .= "<p><b>Name : </b>".$array['name']." <span><b>Qty : </b>".$array['quantity']." pcs </span><span><b>Price : </b>AUD ".$array['price']." </span><span><b>Total : </b>AUD ".$subtotal." </span></p>";    
  mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE allproduct SET sold=sold+1 WHERE id= '".$array['product_id']."'");
}
```